# More efficient way of looping through IPs for specific devices

Tags: powershell, foreach, ping

I have the following code. IT more or less works. It just seems slow in terms of it gets hung on offline IPs.

So my question is this.

Is the ideal way to loop through IPs doing a quick ping, then loop through the live IPs?

Another thought was to pull device type but as these are phones, you can't use the WMI- functions for example like you could with computers.

My end game goal is I want to run a script and force a reboot of every VoIP phone on the network.

```
$ping = new-object system.net.networkinformation.ping
    1..255 | foreach { $IPS = "192.168.2.$_"
    $Res = $ping.send($IPS)
        if ($Res.Status -eq "Success") 
        { 
                 $user = 'admin'
                 $pass = 'admin'
                 $pair = "$($user):$($pass)"
                 $encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
                 $basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"
                 $Headers = @{
                     Authorization = $basicAuthValue
                    }
            $URL = "http://"+$IPS+"/servlet?key=Reboot"
            Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -Headers $Headers
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Stumbled upon Powershell Workflows as an alternative to running jobs in parallel.

```
workflow Restart-Phones {
    Param( [string]$Phones )

    foreach -parallel ($phone in $phones) {

        sequence {
            $result = Test-Connection $Phone -Count 1 -Quiet

            if ($result) {

                $user = 'admin'
                $pass = 'admin'
                $pair = "$($user):$($pass)"
                $encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
                $basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"
                $Headers = @{
                    Authorization = $basicAuthValue
                }
                $URL = "http://"+$IPS+"/servlet?key=Reboot"
                Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -Headers $Headers
            }
        }
    }
}

$Phones = 1..255 | % { "192.168.2.$_" }

Restart-Phones $Phones
```

### Original

You could try something like this (note: I haven't run the whole thing). The idea being that you would create a powershell job running a separate instance of $RebootScript for each $IP you want to call. That way you're not held up by each unresponsive ping, just that instance of the script is.

```
$RebootScript = {
    Param($IP)

    $ping = new-object system.net.networkinformation.ping
    $res = $ping.send($IP)

    if ($res.Status -eq "Success") {

        $user = 'admin'
        $pass = 'admin'
        $pair = "$($user):$($pass)"
        $encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
        $basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"
        $Headers = @{
            Authorization = $basicAuthValue
        }
        $URL = "http://"+$IPS+"/servlet?key=Reboot"
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -Headers $Headers
    }
}

$jobs = @() #Empty array

1..255 | foreach { 
    $IP = "192.168.2.$_"

    $jobs += Start-Job -ScriptBlock $RebootScript -ArgumentList $IP

}

# Wait until all jobs are finished.
Get-Job | Wait-Job

# Get and display jobs.
Get-Job | Receive-Job
```

I'm not sure about the ping object, but you can use the Test-Connection cmdlet to limit the ping count to 1. I used Measure-Command to test the difference and it seemed to help. However, you'd need to change your conditional to ($res.statuscode -contains 0)

```
Test-Connection -ComputerName $IP -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: Does test-connection still work even if it is not a computer? And how does the $res.statuscode tie in with test-connection?

Comment: @FrankThornton Looks like you've already figured out how you wanted to use it, but the $res variable would have contained a Win32_PingStatus object. To see if it passed or failed you'd inspect the statuscode property but as you've found with the -quiet parameter, Test-Connection will just return a bool value instead. And -computer can be any device with an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution that seems to work in a decent manner:

```
1..255 | %{
$IP = "192.168.2.$_"
    If (Test-Connection -count 1 -comp $IP -quiet) {
        $user = 'admin'
        $pass = 'admin'
        $pair = "$($user):$($pass)"
        $encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
        $basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"
        $Headers = @{
            Authorization = $basicAuthValue
        }
        $URL = "http://"+$IP+"/servlet?key=Reboot"
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -Headers $Headers
    }
}
```